# JSON schema enum vs pattern for single value

Tags: json, enums, jsonschema, json-api

I have an sample json:

```
{
    "type": "persons",
    "id": 2,
    "attributes": {
        "first": "something",
        "second": "something else"
    }
}
```

And I have to make a schema for it (using [JSON API specs](http://jsonapi.org/format/%20%22JSON%20API%20specs) and [JSON schema docs](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html)):

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^persons$"
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "attributes": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {...}
        }
    },
    "required": ["type", "id", "attributes"]
}
```

And the question is: if the only acceptable value for "type" is "persons", should I use in schema pattern (like above) or enum like

```
"enum": ["persons"]
```

I couldn't get any clear answer from documentation, although in examples in specs enums are used for single values. So what's your opinion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ultimately, it doesn't really matter.  Both will work and both are reasonable.  That said, the most common approach I've seen is to use `enum`.  Neither are perfect for readability, but I think `enum` is better for two reasons.

1. Using `pattern` requires two lines to express.  Using `enum` requires only one because `type` is implied by the value in the array.  Two lines are harder to read than one, so if that line is expressive enough, I say stick with one.
2. Not everyone is comfortable reading regex.  `enum` might be more accessible for that reason.

Answer (score 12):

Since draft-6 there is a new keyword called `const` for this use-case.

```
"type": {
        "type": "string",
        "const": "persons"
},
```

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.1.3

Comment: I don't think you need `type` when using `const`.